# excel - calculate remaining mondays in each month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I pay a bill every monday.  I want to know how much more this is going to cost me this month.

How do I calculate how many mondays are in an upcoming month?  For the current month, how do I calculate remaining mondays after today?

Answer (score 5):

How many Mondays remaining this month (excluding today if it's a Monday)

```
=INT((EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)-TODAY()+WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3))/7)
```

How many Mondays next month

```
=INT((EOMONTH(TODAY(),1)-EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0),3))/7)
```

References:
[`EOMONTH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314FFA1-2BC9-4005-9D66-F49DB127D628)
[`WEEKDAY`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a?NS=EXCEL&Version=90&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL900&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60118&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Can you explain this formula a bit. Lets say i want to know remaining Tuesdays instead of mondays, what is the change that need to be done?

Comment: I just tested this - you change the 3 in 'WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3))' to one of a few various values. 1 through 3 or 11 through 13 are valid entries. If you enter the formula in Excel the equation helper will give you the table. It's rather long to reproduce here. I found that for Wednesdays left in the month, I wanted the value 13, which represents "Numbers 1 (Wednesday) through 7 (Tuesday)".